# i am having 400 POST bad request error and having this error in status "json value could not be converted to syatem.string. path"

Tags: reactjs, json, post, form-submit, 400-bad-request

400 POST bad request

I want when I submit form then it will submit details and do not show 400 Post bad request error...submit my details and refresh form and it will not show me "json value could not be converted to system .string. path" error

Comment: Please add a supporting code to have a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.